# How to get the last pull time in Google Container Registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I want to delete some stale images in GCR, but currently, I can only delete images based on the creation time as in the script [here](https://gist.github.com/ahmetb/7ce6d741bd5baa194a3fac6b1fec8bb7).

Therefore, how can I get the last pull time of images, so I can then decide whether they should be deleted?

Comment: is this still not possible?

Answer (score 2):

GCR does not store last pull date at this point but I think it would be nice to have as it would make image management a little bit easier. But if the image has not been pulled for a while it does not mean that it is not used.

**Keep Last N versions**

Depending on how images are versioned you could bake the deletion in the build pipeline. When your main pipeline run completes successfully and creates a new job gets triggered that cleans up the oldest image once you have more than n images (say more than 10 images).

**Untag / Retag Strategy for image maintenance**

Or you can simply change the tag from v2 to v2-tobe-deleted for the images you consider old and keep it for a grace period of time. See if any apps in production has any issues. If all looks well after few days (or weeks or months) then you schedule the versions to be deleted. Or restore the tag if you see any issues.

**Check Image versions used in GKE before deleting**

Ideally, you'd want to query [your production cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/) assuming you are using GKE to get all image versions and delete unused image version which are older than certain date:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{..image}" |\
tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' |\
sort |\
uniq -c
```

OR

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Has there been any development on this front? or last pull time is still not available?