# Looking for a middleware or proxy for Google Container Registry

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, docker-image, google-container-registry

Currently, I am using self-hosted harbor repo for the docker repository.

Due to some reasons, I must migrate away from the above harbor repo.
Currently, most/all of our infra is in GCP, so I was thinking of migrating to GCR.
There are a few blockers with the GCR:

- it doesn't provide information, like when was the last time a certain image was pulled. I need this information, to clean up images which haven't been used in the last 1 month. Currently, I get all this data from harbor repo, and using a script, can clean older images.

Some solutions:

- Manage the list of images being pulled in GKE, and use this for cleanup.
- Use a middleware or proxy to GCR, which can provide me with this data. For this, I looked into harbor. And this harbor can run on the same GKE cluster and will work as a proxy cache too. But Harbor will keep a copy of each of the images, it proxies, and even older images as well, i.e. it will work as a persistent repo, and not just a cache. I don't want to do that.

Is there any better way to do this? Or any other software/tool, which I can use to implement this.
Any suggestions would be helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59716409/18265570) And if `container registry` generates auditing events,  then these will be written to `Cloud Logging`. `Cloud Logging` can then export to `BigQuery` and then you can "ask" `BigQuery`, when was the last time someone pulled the image.

Comment: Suggestion: do not delete images based on the last pull date unless you also track where those images are being served.